# Vauxhall Corsa Ecoflex 2013 - Map is showing me about 2 miles away

Tags: corsa, navigation, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, infotainment

I've had my Corsa since July last year.  Last night on my drive home I noticed the satnav was showing my location as around 2 miles away from where I actually was.  I hoped whatever it was would be gone today, but wherever I go, it makes a paralel trip about 2 miles away from where I actually am.  Has anyone come across this?  By the way, by satnav I mean the car's infotainment system.  Any help would be most appreciated as I'm due to go on a trip in a couple of weeks' time and really need this solved by then!  Thank you.

Comment: Have you updated the maps in the car's system? That and a reset would probably sort it...

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, thank you for your reply.  I'm going to pull the "girl card"... I have no idea how to do either!  Any help on this would be most appreciated. :)

Comment: Weel, a quick search gave this : https://www.vauxhall.co.uk/owners/factory-sat-nav-updates.html and this, which might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3_26m5u4Ck

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike, the upgrade looks quite expensive, I was hoping for a reset that could be done on the current system, and the youtube link only shows how to use the navigation system not how to reset.  I'm still holding out hope that someone out there has a magic way of doing this.  Really appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: Well, you could try the local dealer, ask if there is reset option (with a nice smile... :) ) amazing how asking nicely helps... If you tell them the issue of 2 miles, they may say "oh yes, that's xxx"...

Comment: Thanks Mike, i will certainly try that! have a lovely day.